# Read ringtone string assigned to Contact on iOS

Tags: iphone

using iOS sdk 4.3

In order to determine the phone numbers a contact has on iOS one can use the code below

```
    ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    CFIndex i = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier (multi,identifier);

    phoneNumberLabel = (CFStringRef)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
    phoneNumber      = (NSMutableString* )ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
```

However what property type ie kABPersonxxxProperty will give me the string value of the Ringtone for a contact. This is all i need, just to read the string.

Thanks